# Do I have to destroy an object once I am done?

Tags: c#, class, object, destructor

In C#, do I have to ***always*** destroy an object once I am done with it? If not, on what conditions do I have to destroy the object and call the destructor? What will happen if I don't destroy the object? What are the pros and cons?

Simple Example:

```
Help h = new Help();

h.program_name = "myprogram.exe";
h.release_date = "01/10/2013";
h.version_number = "1.2.0.0"; 

if (args.Length > 0)
{
    if ((args[0] == "-help") || (args[0] == "-version")||(args[0] == "/?"))
    {
        h.writeline();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this an example of?

Answer (score 11):

Unless the object implements the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface, there's no need for you to do anything with it when you're done using it.

Let the Garbage Collector do its job and all will be well and right in the world.

Answer (score 5):

Only objects that deal with unmanaged resources need to be explicitly disposed. These types should implement the IDisposable interface. A good way to deal with these objects is by using the `using` keyword:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    // ...do stuff with conn
}  // conn.Dispose() will automatically be called here
```

Comment: How do I know if I have "objects that deal with unmanaged memory"

Comment: @JohnRyann The biggest clue is when they implement IDisposable.

Comment: And for MS's APIs, you'll see this declaration in the syntax of the class. Take a look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx](SPSite) for instance, and you'll see `public class SPSite : IDisposable`.

Comment: @John Ryann one good clue is when you use pinvokes and obtain a handle back often as IntPtr values. When you deal with such things you should explicitly release them.

Answer (score 2):

In general C# uses a garbage collector, so there is no need to "destruct" objects manually.

In some cases you might want to immediately free resources associated with some objects, like network/database connections, open files, etc. Using 'using' is often the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you don't need to distroy ***always***, but only when needed.
Normally when you design a class you will declare and implement an [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface that does the actual cleanup if necessary. You ***need*** to take care of possible unmanaged resources that your class instances might allocate and the overloaded [Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method is the best place you should take care of them and deallocate them.

Be careful, the [Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method should be designes so that it can be called multiple times without crashing, so pay close attention and check any obect reference against null value. This is a good practice all over your code, but Dispose() method needs more attention regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned there is `GC` in C# to clean object.

There is no destructor in `C#`, but there is `finalizer` which being called when object is collected. But there is no need to implement finalizer in most of cases.

Some information about Finalize method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx

If we need specific behavior for object disposing (for example cleaning up unmanaged resources) you should implement Finalize method.

This is the way how you can do it: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Beware implementing Finalize, it causes [double work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx#dotnetgcbasics_topic5) for GC to clean this object.

Comment: There **are** destructors in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in terminology.